# Grafana query filter by key and value

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, grafana

In my Grafana ElasticSearch Datasource, I have an attribute like this:

```
=== object_attributes.variables ====
[ 
  { "key": "fruit", "value": "apple" }, 
  { "key": "fruit", "value": "banana" }, 
  { "key": "game", "value": "cricket" }, 
  { "key": "game", "value": "football" }
]

=== object_attributes.status =====
["failed","all","xxx"] or ["passed","all","xxx"]
```

So, When I Query like this

1. `* AND object_attributes.status:"passed"` I get Expected Results
2. `* AND object_attributes.status:"passed" AND object_attributes.variable:{ "key": "fruit", "value": "banana" }`  I get no results.

Basically, I want to filter all attributes by `fruit: banana` and `passed`. So, How Do I modify point 2 to get results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself.

I was running the Query below and I was able to get the results as expected.

```
* AND object_attributes.status:"passed" AND object_attributes.variable.key:"fruit" AND object_attributes.variable.value:"banana"
```

So, Instead of Running `object_attributes.variable:{ "key": "fruit", "value": "banana" }` I was running both `object_attributes.variable.key:"fruit" AND object_attributes.variable.value:"banana"` and its working like a charm.